# How to monitor tasks in standard standalone Spring application

Tags: angularjs, spring, monitoring

I have created a standard standalone spring application which uses threadpools to submits multiple tasks and these tasks creates files and I am loggin these activities in log files and in an audit table. The application is JMX enabled and we are using JConsole to monitor. I am exploring ready-made options(open-source) so that I can monitor file creation tasks.

I think, it's best to create client web application (GUI SPA app) using latest spring, angular js technologies which can hook into the application so that I can monitor real-time data and can be used at production level.

Please help to desgin, develop and select right technologies for the purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to get better viewing of application events.  Assuming you are comfortable using jmx I recommend adding a few custom mbeans that track whatever you would like monitored.  Once you have done that you can expose your application's jmx mbeans like a restful webservice leveraging Jolokia:  https://jolokia.org/  Now that you have a restful webservice you can simply build any kind of frontend monitoring tool.  If you would like to avoid building something completely I recommend looking into AppDynamics: https://www.appdynamics.com/java/

Comment: I am learning about Jolokia but on web I do not find enough materials so that I can make use of that. Can you please how I can integrate jolokia in my project and run on Jetty if possible

Comment: Sure.  Jolokia is really more like a "plugin" to your jvm.  It will allow you to expose all of the Java JMX mbeans as a restful webservice.  Using that restful webservice you can build a very detailed dashboard program.